# Error Upgrading DB to 5.15.alpha1 on Drupal 7: SQL error

Tags: drupal, upgrade, evaluating-civicrm

When I am trying to Upgrade the DB to 5.15.alpha1, some SQL error is occurring.
How can I fix the error as given below:

> $Fatal Error Details = Array ( [callback] => Array ( [0] =>
>   CRM_Core_Error [1] => exceptionHandler ) [code] => -1 [message] => DB
>   Error: unknown error [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => INSERT INTO
>   `civicrm_option_value` (`option_group_id`, `label`, `value`, `name`,
>   `weight`, `is_reserved`, `is_active`, `is_default`) SELECT
>   @option_group_id_ps as option_group_id, label, value, ov.name, weight,
>   ov.is_reserved, ov.is_active, is_default FROM civicrm_option_value ov
>   INNER JOIN civicrm_option_group og ON og.id = ov.option_group_id AND
>   og.name = 'contribution_status' [nativecode=1052 * Column 'label' in
>   field list is ambiguous] [type] => DB_Error [user_info] => INSERT INTO
>   `civicrm_option_value` (`option_group_id`, `label`, `value`, `name`,
>   `weight`, `is_reserved`, `is_active`, `is_default`) SELECT
>   @option_group_id_ps as option_group_id, label, value, ov.name, weight,
>   ov.is_reserved, ov.is_active, is_default FROM civicrm_option_value ov
>   INNER JOIN civicrm_option_group og ON og.id = ov.option_group_id AND
>   og.name = 'contribution_status' [nativecode=1052 * Column 'label' in
>   field list is ambiguous] [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error:
>   unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback
>   callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="INSERT INTO
>   `civicrm_option_value` (`option_group_id`, `label`, `value`, `name`,
>   `weight`, `is_reserved`, `is_active`, `is_default`) SELECT
>   @option_group_id_ps as option_group_id, label, value, ov.name, weight,
>   ov.is_reserved, ov.is_active, is_default FROM civicrm_option_value ov
>   INNER JOIN civicrm_option_group og ON og.id = ov.option_group_id AND
>   og.name = 'contribution_status' [nativecode=1052 ** Column 'label' in
>   field list is ambiguous]"] )

Please advice.

Comment: Are you using mysql 8?

Comment: Not sure which version we are using now! Could you please advice me from where I can check the mysql version? Thank You!

Comment: Go to /admin/reports/status and look for database system version.

Comment: Database system version:   5.5.5-10.0.23-MariaDB-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is in line 8 in [CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/5.15.alpha1.mysql.tpl](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/7c907de0574a3fd76aacc9264d5fbbef54f33b8f/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/5.15.alpha1.mysql.tpl#L8) you can change it from

```
SELECT @option_group_id_ps as option_group_id, {localize field='label'}`label`{/localize}, value, ov.name, weight, ov.is_reserved, ov.is_active, is_default
```

to

```
SELECT @option_group_id_ps as option_group_id, ov.{localize field='label'}`label`{/localize}, ov.value, ov.name, ov.weight, ov.is_reserved, ov.is_active, ov.is_default
```

Comment: Okay, I will check it and inform you. Thank you.

Comment: This is worked for me. Thank You!

Comment: Great. Glad it worked.